# Just starting off with C++, not registering command

Tags: cout, endl

I'm not really sure why "cout" and "endl" are not being recognized. Any help would be great!

The error is:
[image]

and the code is:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `iostream` has a red squiggle underneath it is a near certainty that you have something wrong with your environment (such as compiling with a C compiler rather than a C++ one, for *example*).

You need to fix that, since `cout` and `endl` are *defined* in that header. I'd start by hovering the mouse over the `iostream` text and see what the tooltip shows you.

If it cannot find the file `iostream` then you're either not using a C++ compiler, or your environment is severely damaged.

Either way, it's not a *correct* C++ environment.

Things to look in to are (to start with):

- Examine the file extension. Using `*.c` instead of `*.cpp` may use a C compiler rather than a C++ one, for example).
- Examine the output of your compilation, if available. You will hopefully be able to tell which compiler is being used.

If you *are* sure you're using a C++ compiler:

- You might have a funny character in your `iostream` string. You could totally delete that line and retype it (don't edit, it may not get rid of the funny character).
- Try a different header (like `cstdlib`) to see if it has the same problem.
- Last-straw solution would be re-installation of your development environment, in case things are so damaged it's unrecoverable.

Comment: It says "'iostream' file not found"